# auto expand div height not working

Tags: html, css

This is my design code. Problem is I have slider in which Image sizes I have set according to screen size. But my problem is content below slider is overlapping on slider part. What should happen is in any screen below slider that content should come. If I specify the min-image size then when screen size gets reduce it leaves lot of blank space.

HTML Code.

```
<!--slide-part-starts--><div class="slide-part">
    <!--slider-starts--><div class="fadein">
<img style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.location.href='http://myevio.com/powerock-13600mAh-powerbank.html'" src="BG Slideshow/1.jpg"><!--powerock-->
<img style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.location.href='http://myevio.com/powerpunch-10500mAh-powerbank.html'" src="BG Slideshow/2.jpg"><!--powerpunch-->
</div><!--slide-ends-->
</div><!--slide-part-ends-->

<!--about-evio-starts--><div class="about-evio">
At EViO, we make tech gear that helps improve productivity,<br />
so that you have more time to do the essential things - living life to the fullest.
</div><!--about-evio-ends-->
```

CSS

```
.slide-part{
    width:100%;
    max-width:1600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height:100px;
    height:100%
}

.fadein {
    position:relative; 
    width:100%; 
    max-width:1600px; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    min-height:100px;
    height:100%
}

.fadein img {
    position:absolute; 
    left:0; 
    top:0; 
    height:auto; 
    max-width:100%; 
    width: auto\9;
}

.about-evio{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:50px 0 50px 0;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
    min-height:20px;
    background:#fff;
    font-size:1.2em;
    line-height:30px
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/13b99zou/).

You need to check out the width/height ratio and adjust the padding-top with specific percentage value so the image shows nicely.

HTML:

```
<!--slide-part-starts--><div class="slide-part">
<!--slider-starts--><div class="fadein">
<img style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.location.href='http://myevio.com/powerock-13600mAh-powerbank.html'" src="http://placehold.it/1150x350"><!--powerock-->
<img style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.location.href='http://myevio.com/powerpunch-10500mAh-powerbank.html'" src="http://placehold.it/1150x350"><!--powerpunch-->
</div><!--slide-ends-->
</div><!--slide-part-ends-->

<!--about-evio-starts--><div class="about-evio">
At EViO, we make tech gear that helps improve productivity,<br />
so that you have more time to do the essential things - living life to the fullest.
</div><!--about-evio-ends-->
```

CSS:

```
.slide-part{
    width:100%;
    max-width:1600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height:100px;
    height:100%
}

.fadein {
    padding-top: 27%;
    position:relative; 
    width:100%; 
    max-width:1600px; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    min-height:100px;
    height:100%
}

.fadein img {
    position:absolute; 
    left:0; 
    top:0; 
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%; 
}

.about-evio{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:50px 0 50px 0;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
    min-height:20px;
    background:#fff;
    font-size:1.2em;
    line-height:30px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `.slide-part` `min-height` to slider image height

See this example

```css
.slide-part{
    width:100%;
    max-width:1600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height:300px;
    height:100%
}

.fadein {
    position:relative; 
    width:100%; 
    max-width:1600px; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    min-height:100px;
    height:100%
}

.fadein img {
    position:absolute; 
    left:0; 
    top:0; 
    height:auto; 
    max-width:100%; 
    width: auto\9;
}

.about-evio{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:50px 0 50px 0;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
    min-height:20px;
    background:#fff;
    font-size:1.2em;
    line-height:30px
}
```

```html
<!--slide-part-starts--><div class="slide-part">
    <!--slider-starts--><div class="fadein">
<img style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.location.href='http://myevio.com/powerock-13600mAh-powerbank.html'" src="http://www.callbox.com.co/programacionWeb/bitramParking/slide_img/images/example/parking_ruta.jpg"><!--powerock-->
<img style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.location.href='http://myevio.com/powerpunch-10500mAh-powerbank.html'" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-z-1cdSTPYww/Th8pXvziI7I/AAAAAAAAG5k/j9EglrHT_Ik/s1600/20.jpg"><!--powerpunch-->
</div><!--slide-ends-->
</div><!--slide-part-ends-->

<!--about-evio-starts--><div class="about-evio">
At EViO, we make tech gear that helps improve productivity,<br />
so that you have more time to do the essential things - living life to the fullest.
</div><!--about-evio-ends-->
```

Comment: that is the problem if do this then there is blank space coming between slider image and below content. I want content should come exactly below slide without any blank spaces.

Comment: So if I reduce min-height then it's overlapping.

Comment: That will not be my solution then because image is set for auto size according to screen.

Comment: change .fadein img {position:absolute;} to .fadein img {position:relative;}